# Magento 2.4.6: $_isFixed must not be defined error in custom shipping module

Tags: php, magento2.4, fatal-error

I have coded a custom shipping module for Magento 2.4.6 according to Adobe's documentation here: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/frontend/custom-checkout/add-shipping-carrier/

I am receiving the following error upon running a static content deployment:

*Fatal error:  Type of MyModules\CustomShipping1\Model\Carrier\Customshipping::$_isFixed must not be defined (as in class Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier) in /var/www/html/app/code/MyModules/CustomShipping1/Model/Carrier/Customshipping.php on line 18*

My code for the Customshipping.php is below:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyModules\CustomShipping1\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Customshipping extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
{
    protected $_code = 'customshipping';

    protected bool $_isFixed = true;

    private ResultFactory $rateResultFactory;

    private MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);

        $this->rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Custom Shipping Rates Collector
     *
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result|bool
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        /** @var Method $method */
        $method = $this->rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        $shippingCost = (float) $this->getConfigData('shipping_cost');
        $method->setPrice($shippingCost);
        $method->setCost($shippingCost);

        /** @var Result $result */
        $result = $this->rateResultFactory->create();
        $result->append($method);

        return $result;
    }

    public function getAllowedMethods(): array
    {
        return [$this->_code => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }
}
```

I had changed protected string $_code = 'customshipping'; to the current iteration shown above to try and solve the issue but that did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the **bool** from the following line of code and it will work properly.

```
protected bool $_isFixed = true;
```

Use it like this:

```
protected $_isFixed = true;
```

**Note:** I have tested the same & it seems to be working fine in all the cases.